# How to put html code into template in Django

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-templates

Trying to send to template html code from another html file.
The view code looks like:

```
def homepage( request ):

    return render(request, 'homepage.html', {
        'table': generateTable(),
    })

def generateTable():
    x = render_to_response( 'tableSchema.html' )
    return x
```

And in a template:

```
{{ table|safe }}
```

Everything is okay, but I see an information about UTF8 above the table :
I mean the table is generating correctly ,but above is the following text:

> Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

Do you know why and how to remove it ?
Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`render_to_response` does exactly what the name suggests: renders the template *and creates a response*. You don't want a response, you just want the rendered string: so use `render_to_string`.

However, a more natural way of doing this would be to use a template tag or include inside the template itself.